# Sum multiple annotates in django orm

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views

Here's my model:

```
class Product:
  name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
  price = models.FloatField()
  category = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

```
class ProductInventory:
  inventory = models.IntegerField()
  product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

and here's raw sql of what I want to achieve but how do I write this in django ORM?

```
SELECT product.category, SUM(price) * SUM(product_inventory.inventory) 
FROM product LEFT JOIN product_inventory 
ON product.id=product_inventory.product_id group by product.category;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using Sum in annotate and make a dummy field of name sum_product and pass it in values like this. Hope this will work for you.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Product.objects.annotate(sum_product=Sum('price') * Sum('productinventory__inventory')).values('category', 'sum_product')
```